# Is it possible to setup an interface with both DHCP and a static IP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

Sending a box out to a colo and the guy taking it has no idea of networking. was hoping I could set it up so I can access it no matter which of two switches he plugs it into. After which I can remove one of the entries.

Something like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0:0 inet dhcp
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 66.66.66.220
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 66.66.66.254
broadcast 66.66.66.223
```

Comment: Try modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`, and adding more Ethernet devices and set address and netmask values on them. 
(eth0, eth0:0, eth0:0:0 and so on)

Answer (score 2):

Finally got someone at the console just in case, but this works.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 66.66.66.220
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 66.66.66.254
broadcast 66.66.66.223
```